# Drupal selectors changed after upgrading from 8.8.5 to 8.9.3

Tags: 8, views, updating

I just upgraded from `8.8.5` to `8.9.3` and I am noticing some of my CSS was broken. After inspecting, I am noticing the selectors on my view have changed. Before my filter submit button was selected via `data-drupal-selector="edit-submit-inventory-listing"` but after updating, it now has a `2` appended to the end, thus breaking my css selector. The drupal selector now reads `data-drupal-selector="edit-submit-inventory-listing-2"`. Any ideas? I would expect that to happen if the view was on the page twice, but its not

Comment: Have you tried searching on drupal.org? These issues may be relevant: [Apply and use data-drupal-selector consistently](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2509970), [Replace #ID selectors for data-drupal-selector attribute](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2346799).

Comment: I did search the issue queue and I even came across those two. I ended up just modifying my CSS. Not ideal, but it worked.